# KO's component hierarchy (or lack thereof)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Does KnockoutJS support some kind of component hierarchy or scoping? Essentially, I'm looking for something like this:

```
ko.components['parent'].components.register('child1', ...)
```

I don't see anything like that in the documentation. Without that I have to enforce that all my components have a globally unique name.

Comment: Just like binding handlers have to be globally unique and template IDs have to be globally unique. There is only a single component registry in knockout.

Answer (score 2):

I think having one global object that sort of fakes the namespacing should be sufficient to prevent name clashes. For example:

```js
var c = {
  editor: {
    message: "c.editor.message"
  }
};

ko.components.register(c.editor.message, {
    viewModel: function(params) {
        this.text = ko.observable(params && params.initialText || '');
    },
    template: 'Message: <input data-bind="textInput: text" /> '
            + '(length: <span data-bind="text: text().length"></span>)'
});
 
ko.applyBindings();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind='component: c.editor.message'></div>
```

(Example component taken from [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-binding.html))

You could even wrap the `register` method to automatically create namespaces and deal with undefined namespaces via a helper. Might make stuff unnecessarily complicated though. Still, I think it's a good idea that you somehow "protect" the global component namespace to prevent overwrites.

```js
var c = (function() {
  var components = {};
  
  var register = function(path, opts) {
    return path
      .reduce(function(pos, k, i, arr) {
        if (i >= arr.length - 1) {
          if (pos[k]) {
            throw new Error("Component name [" + arr + "] already in use");
          }
          
          pos[k] = arr.join("--");
          ko.components.register(pos[k], opts);
        } else {
          pos[k] = pos[k] || {};
        }
      
        return pos[k];
      }, components);
  };
  
  var get = function() {
     return Array.from(arguments)
       .reduce(function(pos, k) {
         return k ? pos[k] || k : null;
       }, components);
  };
  
  return {
    register: register,
    get: get
  };
}());

c.register(["editor", "message"], {
    viewModel: function(params) {
        this.text = ko.observable(params && params.initialText || '');
    },
    template: 'Message: <input data-bind="textInput: text" /> '
            + '(length: <span data-bind="text: text().length"></span>)'
});
 
ko.applyBindings();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind='component: c.get("editor", "message")'></div>
```